# How to forward multipart data(csv file and string) from node server to spring controller?

Tags: node.js, spring, express, multer

I'm tring to pass the multipart/form-data from node server to spring mvc controller. Post a csv file and a string to node server, then it handles the request with using multer middleware and forwards it to spring controller that takes form object as a parameter, and I can access the csv file and string through that object.

**spring**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someController", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public someResponse someController(SomeForm s) {
    // LOGIC: use this "s" object
}

public  class SomeForm{
    private MultipartFile mf;
    private String str;

    // getter and setter

}
```

**node**

```
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
router.use(upload.any());

router.post('/someEndPoint', (req, res) => {
    let reqHeaders = {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }

    let reqToSome = {
        mf: req.file,
        str: req.body.string,
    }

    let options = {
        headers: reqHeaders,
        formData: reqToSome,
    }

    request.post("baseurl/someController", options, callbackfunc)

}
```

**postman**

- posting uri: baseurl/someEndPoint
- headers: content-type,multipart/form-data
- body: csvFile, sample.csv
       string, "aaa"

[cf. pic of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Lz9i.png)

When I post this data from postman to my node server, I got an error like this :

```
"TypeError: source.on is not a function"
```

and no request was sent to spring controller.

I googled this error message, but couldn't understand what it is...

Then I changed 
`formData: reqToSome` 
to 
`formData: JSON.stringify(reqToSome)`.

This time, spring controller get the request from node. Request was successfully completed. **But both s.mf and s.str were null.**

Now I'm assuming I have to parse reqToSome to some kind of data form so as to fit the MultipartFile class. If that's correct, how can I do that? If not, what approach should I take? I want to get the sample.csv and "aaa" on spring controller from the SomeForm object.

**req.file and req.body.string are like this**

string is `'aaa'`

csvFile is

```
{ fieldname: 'csvFile',
  originalname: 'sample.csv',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'text/csv',
  buffer: <Buffer 6f 72 67 31 2c 20 70 69 64 31 2c 20 31 2c 20 30 0d 0a 6f 72 67 32 2c 20 70 69 64 32 2c 20 31 2c 20 30 0d 0a 6f 72 67 33 2c 20 70 69 64 33 2c 20 30 2c ... >,
  size: 52 }
```

I'm quite newbee about these tech field and really confused. Any advices would be appriciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar use case and this is how I solved it.

You Spring boot controller is fine, we need the below implementation in node.

```js
const {Router} = require('express')
const multer = require('multer')
const FormData = require('form-data')
const axios = require('axios')

const routes = Router()
const storage = multer.memoryStorage()
const upload = multer({storage: storage})

routes.post('/someEndPoint', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
  const {file} = req
  const {buffer, originalname: filename} = file
  const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('file', buffer, {
    filename,
  })

  axios.post('/baseUrl/someController', formData, {
    headers: {
      ...formData.getHeaders()
    }
  }).then(response => response)
})
```

The form-data npm package is the important part here.